# Duplicate closure, possible or is it a bug?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I just saw these two questions are closed as duplicate of each other, forming a closure:

- [Subscript out of range error in this excel vba script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817399/subscript-out-of-range-error-in-this-excel-vba-script)
- [Updated the vba code and still it gives me a subscript out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818319/updated-the-vba-code-and-still-it-gives-me-a-subscript-out-of-range-error)

The first one is a duplicate of the second one, and the second one is a dupe of first. Is this even possible? Isn't this a bug or flaw in the system?

I tried manually closing a dupe of a dupe and I got this response:

[image]

Now how was the above two questions closed?

Comment: This was possible in the past, and was fixed a while ago

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh okay... :)

Comment: How does the system now try to get rid of the closed rings?

Comment: Looks like it was fixed twice already, but still not enough.

Comment: It's still possible somehow, not sure how - but surely it is. :)

Comment: Note that those questions were dupe-circled back in 2013 so it's possible that this issue *is* resolved; the other question you linked @ShadowWizard is from late 2015

Comment: @TylerH they were closed in November, the "fix" was applied in July.